# Post request working on web simulator but not on the app

Tags: rest, post, web-applications, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

i am making a tizen application for samsung gear s3 and im trying to send a post request using javascript when i launch my application on the web simulator the request work fine but when i launch the app on my device the request doesnt work

I added the internet privilege on the config.xml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function send(){
        console.log("1");
        var data = "<m2m:>";

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
          }
        });

        xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/~/in-cse/in-name/MY_SENSOR/DATA");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-M2M-Origin", "admin:admin");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;ty=4");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

        xhr.send(data);
        console.log("end");
    }
    </script>
```

for the result my server need to add the m2m on his side, but thats something relevent because its working on postman

I think its a issue with the cors policy, do you know how i can fix that?

Thanks for your time

Comment: My experience is with Tizen .NET apps but if the Watch is not connected directly to the internet via wifi or LTE, but is connected via a phone over bluetooth, then you need to set the phone as a proxy in the web request.  Let me know if that is the case and I can share code.

Comment: thanks for answer, she is directly connected with wifi

Answer (score 1):

I did some research about this topic and it seems to me that you need to add the access domain in config.xml of your application. [Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/application-development-process/setting-project-properties#policy) says that adding:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1:8081/~/in-cse/in-name/MY_SENSOR/DATA" subdomains="true"/>
```

should help with this problem. You can also find [more information about CORS on Tizen](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/security/cross-origin-resource-sharing)